# Cycle through search results pages and halt when the last page is found

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I can not seem to grasp the following implementation technique:

```
page = '0'

for new_page_num in range(int(page)+120, 100000, 120):
url = 'https://example.com/search/' + str(new_page_num) + 'remainder of url'

print(url.format(new_page_num))
```

Here I have the code to cycle through pages by it's url pattern, incremental of 120.

How do I make the program do certain actions on each page and how do I give the program a landmark when it is the last page to halt the process of scrapping results or whatever I want to do there.

I am also specifically addressing the question where to put the scrapping code into? which section of the code?

Comment: The indentation in your code sample is wrong. I find it hard to understand exactly what your question is. If you want to exit the for loop before exhausting the range iterator, you can use `if condition: break`

Comment: You've got a `for`-loop that might return unique content on each iteration, have you tested your code, parsed the page content and instructed actions based on the content your code retrieves? The BeautifulSoup documentation has good examples of how to parse the page data, and there are [many other similar questions, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=BeautifulSoup+looping+through+urls) with answers that provide helpful suggestions you could try, and update your question with more specific problems you encounter.

Comment: the code works. I do not know how to set a command when to stop parsing once last page is located

Comment: Inside the for loop, for each page, you are going to hit the url you constructed and read the data from it's response. You can easily check when a url doesn't return a response when you make a request. The parsing also goes inside for loop.